# Classes and inheritance in Java- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, oop, class

I'm new to the concept of classes and inheritance and think I may be a little confused. I am trying to use the MVC design pattern and so thought if I create a "base" model class then I can inherit all my other models from this one so that the view class can accept a reference to any kind of model. Here is my attempt:

```
public class SceneControl {
    SceneView scMaze;
    SceneView scOptions;
    Model ms;

    public SceneControl(ViewPanel view) {
        this.view = view;

        ms = new Maze(31, 20, 5);
        SceneView scMaze = new SceneView(ms);
        ms = new Options(20, 20, 20, 200, 20);
        SceneView scOptions = new SceneView(ms);
...
```

and here is one of my extended model classes:

```
public class Maze extends Model {
    public int i;

    public Maze(int cols, int rows, int ratio) {
        super(cols, rows, ratio);
        i=77;  // a test- can I access this field from inside SceneView
    }
}
```

but when trying to access the extra `Maze` fields inside `SceneView` I get a compiler error

```
public Model ms;

public SceneView(Model ms) {
    this.ms = ms;
    System.out.println(ms.i);  //gives "connot be resolved or is not a field" error
...
```

So I'm guessing my object has been downcast from a `Maze` to a `Model`? How can I pass it to my view class as if it is a `Model` but it still actually be a `Maze`?

Comment: You have a `Model`, not a `Maze`. `Model` does not contain a public filed named `i`

Comment: Rahter than answer, I'll pose you a question to think about: what do you think would happen if you tried to pass a different Model subclass other than Maze, and it did not define field i?

Comment: Hi @Kevin, I was planning to use an if() statement later on to differentiate between the different subclasses... so this is bad OOP?

Comment: Yeah, it's not accepted as good OOP, as indicated by several answers below.  There are better ways at dealing with this.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, can you give me any hints or links that might help me deal with it in a better way? I can't get the subclass to do what I was going to do in my view class because that would be breaking MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you want is something like this (depends on whether you get to define `Model` or not).  This assumes that `i` is not something that every `Model` is going to have, otherwise the suggestion to move i up to the Model is much simpler (and protect it as private and use a getter).

```
public abstract class Model { // or even interface
    public String modelAsString();  // possibly just use Object.toString()
}

public class Maze extends Model { // or implement, if Model is interface
    private int i;
    ...
    public String modelAsString() { return "i = " + i; }
}

public SceneView(Model ms) {
    this.ms = ms;
    System.out.println(m.modelAsString()); // Now any Model subtype will work
```

...

Comment: cheers @Kevin, so its like you suggest using methods to encode each model to a common format that is accessible from the base class, such as encoded into a string?

Comment: Yes, in this case, String is very simplistic to demonstrate, but you might need something more complicated depending on the needs of your view.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `SceneView` constructor has been declared as taking an argument of `Model`, it can only see the members and methods that are in `Model` regardless of what specific subclass the object passed to `SceneView()` is, so it can't see the `i` data member.

Now, why does `SceneView()` need to see `i` at all?  If `SceneView` is really going to work on any subclass of `Model` it can't depend on anything in a subclass.  So `Maze` needs to be written to do whatever `Maze`-specific stuff needs to be done with `i`.

Comment: Hi @QuantumMechanic, thanks for this. So you are saying that with good OOP design anything that is specific to any subclass is dealt with by the class itself rather than using casting? But surely this would break my MVC design pattern as I would have to get my `Maze` class to render itself to the screen when it is supposed to only do Model stuff?

Comment: Maze doesn't have to do the rendering itself.  It only needs to provide the proper input.  But it's good that you are thinking about the appropriate responsibilities in MVC.  It's easy to get sloppy with that.

Answer (score 1):

When passing a generic type, inheritance only works on the basic functionality of the most generic type passed. So for instance, in this case, if not "every" model has `public int i;`, then you cannot access it directly without type-casting (we will get to this in a moment). Furthermore, in this particular case, you can only access functions and variables explicitly defined in the model class since these are guaranteed to be the same for all derived classes.

Now, however, if you know for certain that you have a particular subclass of a given type, then you can type-cast it and access members that way. If you cannot guarantee this though, this is dangerous and could cause some bad bugs.

In this case, to do what you want to, try `System.out.println(((Maze)ms).i);`

Answer (score 0):

You've defined i in "Maze" but tried to access it through a reference to "Model".

You can either cast ms to Maze (and break all kinds of OOP rules) or you have to put it as a member of Model.

Comment: Hi @akhisp, excuse me but I'm not 100% up with the Java lingo yet. By "put it as a member of" do you mean to either have `Maze` as an inner class of model or as an independent class and make an instance of it from `model`?

Comment: he means move the variable `i' from Maze to Model.  Variables that are "members" of a class are often called "fields" too.  Or "instance variables".

Answer (score 0):

It may be a `Maze` but it could also be some other subclass of `Model`. That's why you can't pretend it is definitely a `Maze` and access its members as it may not be one.

If you know somehow it is a `Maze` then why not declare the `SceneView` constructor to take a `Maze`? if you can't, you can still cast it: `((Maze) ms).i` but this is stinky code.

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is that you passed a `Model`, but `Maze` is the class that has the public variable `i`.  (Bad idea, by the way.  You've got big problems with your understanding.)

I think you want to pull `i` up to the `Model` class.  All will be well then.

If you pass in a `Maze`, all will be well because the Liskov substitution principle says a `Maze` IS-A `Model`, so you can pass it to the `SceneView` without a problem.

Comment: See my comment to Anna.  Pulling `i` to `Model` only makes sense if `i` makes sense in all subclasses of `Model`.  If `i` is some `Maze`-specific thing, you do not want to pull it up to the base class.

Comment: Then a Maze isn't a Model.  Or that method needs to take a Maze.  Your design is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is actually a `Maze` you declared it as a `Model`. The compiler will check for the attributes of `Model`, so you will receive a compiler error. You could cast it and it would work.

Comment: You can cast it, but that's generally the sign of a flawed design.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic can you shed any more light on why to cast like this is a sign of flawed design? I am completely new to OOP but it makes sense to me because then my view class can accept references to all types of model class. How is it done with good OOP design?

Comment: Well, it depends.  If `i` is something that would actually be used by all subclasses of `Model`, then yes it would make sense to move it up into `Model`.  But if `i` is something that only makes sense to a `Maze` then you shouldn't -- because if you did, you'd be essentially putting something that only make sense in one specific type of `Model` into all types of `Model`.  That's not a good design.

Answer (score 0):

you could always recast it back by

```
if(ms instanceof maze.class){
//recast back to maze
}
```

but it is kinda hacky, and generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you move the parameter i from class Maze to class Model.

Comment: But if `i` describes some `Maze`-specific state, there's no reason it should be in `Model`.